# A question about Frames Per Second

Tags: performance

When I play a game on my pc, the frames are like 100-130. On Xbox one - PS4 there are some games 30-60fps, 60 frames on pc would be so stuttery. Is there a difference in the console's fps, and the pc's?

Comment: They're running completely different hardware, with different architecture, and code specifically written to be compatible with that specific console.  Yes, they're going to be different.

Comment: 60 fps feels stuttery?  The typical computer monitor only refreshes at 60hz - on those monitors, there is literally no difference between 60fps and 130fps.

Answer (score 0):

Your PC (depending on a variety of things) will normally be able to achieve a higher amount of frames per second. Based on some research the XB1 and the PS4 both have a locked FPS of 60. Your PC may be able to do much higher, unless you have a monitor that is locked to 60Hz. This will only allow it to do 60 FPS. Monitors with a higher refresh rate will display a higher FPS.

Comment: Also consider that the human eye, in most respects, is capped at 60. Unless there is significant fast movement on the screen, you should not notice any blur between frames.

It is for this reason plasma televisions are recommended for sport. With a higher frame rate (200+), a whole bunch cars screaming around a racetrack looks smoother then on a standard LCD. However, for every day programs, the difference is unnoticeable.

If you want a higher FPS on your PC, invest in a plasma monitor or an LCD with a higher refresh rate. From working retail, plasmas are less common but beat LCD display.